# Insert Editable Text Field in Cognos Report (v.8)

Tags: reporting, cognos

**Objective:** Genrate a report in PDF or HTML with an Editable text field (for Comment)

**Purpose:** The PDF or HTML report is delivered to customer (a statement of work). They should be able to type in their comments in the comment field, save the report in their disk.

**Note:** I am not looking for Write-back to server. This is for offline editing and entering comment.

**My handicap:**  I do not have development access in cognos system. But my developer claims, it can not be done. I can not imagine that is

**Research done till now:**  
Example - Add a Multimedia File to a Report

-- In the Insertable Objects pane, on the toolbox tab, drag the HTML Item object to the report. In the HTML dialog box, type the following: PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="/c8/webcontent/samples/images/GO.wmv"

In similar way, can we use PARAM Name="textarea" ?

Comment: you cannot open the report in report studio atleast???

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done that but I have a clue. Insert an HTML part in your report where you would like to add the comments. Put some javascript in such HTML code to read / write using a JSON Web service.

You would need to pass some user's data like his/her username and domain, so they can only modify their own comments.

I think I saw an example in Cognos KB some years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the report as an XLS file? Then the user can add comments to the XLS file as much as they want.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add Text Area into your cognos report.
drag html item into the report
and in HTML Property add the following code.

Comments:

This will add the TextArea where user can write their comments.